# Возможно ли заставить работать приложение, на ПК, где нет необходимой версии офиса?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, office

Возможно ли заставить работать приложение, на ПК, где нет необходимой версии офиса?

Разрабатывал приложение, где стоял 2016 офис, потом кинул приложение на ПК, где 2007 офис и возникли проблемы при запуске...

На машине стоял 2007 офис и я попробовал кинуть библиотеку(Вроде, от 2016) и получил такую ошибку:

> > System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
> >     located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> >     reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'office,
> >     Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
> >
> > ---
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

От офиса я использую только Access, например выполняю запросы, а где-то открываю RecordSet и делаю обновление по одной записи...

Comment: Разбили бы на два вопроса. Тема хоть и общая, но вопросы о разном.

Comment: на вопрос как заставить  работать ответил, а вот про ошибку с библиотекой лучше отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Microsoft для таких случаев есть свободно распространяемые компоненты. Для Access 2016 - можно взять **[тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040)**. Похожие компоненты есть и для некоторых других приложений из пакета MS Office. Эти компоненты не позволяют создавать файлы, но позволяют просмотреть и напечатать, а если Excel- или Access-файл представляет из себя приложение, то и использовать функции такого приложения. По факту эти компоненты содержат все необходимое кроме интерфейса для создания и редактирования, который вы можете реализовать в свое программе.

Таким образом вы можете не требовать от пользователя наличие установленного офиса, а включить в свой инсталятор такой компонент и устанавливать его вместе с приложением, либо оставить выбор за пользователем, ставить себе полный пакет офис или установить только компоненты для просмотра документов, о чем собственно и написано в описании компонента, например `Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime`:

> Microsoft Access 2016 provides a rich platform for developing database
>   management solutions with easy-to-use customization tools. If no
>   end-user customization is required (including report modifications),
>   you can choose to distribute those Access 2016 solutions so that they
>   run without requiring a full installation of Access 2016. To do so,
>   you must package and distribute your application with the Access 2016
>   Runtime.

Comment: Почему-то стала другая ошибка вылетать... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556884/c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-interop