# C# вылетает ошибка при работе с Interop

Tags: c#, .net, com, office-interop

На целевой машине нет Access нужной версии(стоит 2010) и я поставил туда Access 2016 Runtime.

При попытке выполнить программу получаю такую ошибку:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Ошибка при выполнении приложения-сервера (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType
>   objectType) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   serverType) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType
>   serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj) at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at
>   .Clasess.AccessProvider..ctor(String pathToDatabase) in ...

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана такая ошибка?

Использую либы версии 15.0.0.0.

Ошибка возникает в методе, который создает объект Application и пытается открыть БД Access...
Access 2016 Runtime не достаточно для создания объекта?

Подскажите, что с этим делать? Работать через Oledb не предлагать.

Comment: Зачем вы подключаетесь через COM? СУБД Access хорошо подключается и работает через OleDbConnection или OdbcConnection.

Comment: @nick_n_a , нужно выполнять некоторые действия над каждой записью в рекордсет, а грузить всю таблицу в память через адаптер не хочется...

Comment: COM плохо работает, меня подводил на 64-bit сервере.  У с# Хороший IDataReader . Используйте его, конечно понимаю, код переписывать не хочется, но незнаю найдет ли кто ваших "блох" в совместимости приложений. Вот пример ридера https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Касательно ошибки, проверьте ветку реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9}` Обработчик там InprocServer32 (как 64 не знаю). Если ветки нету - у вас что-то не установлено. Если ветка есть - программе не нравится dll-ка - пробуйте другую версию приложения.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вообще вот тут нашел что-то похожее, но не понял ответа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514800/net-access-automation-with-access-2007-runtime ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, покопался в инете и нашел решение:

1)Либы 15.0.0.0. версии относятся к 2013 офису и соответственно я поставил 2013 Runtime

2)Сверху накатил Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies

И все заработало!